# How can I switch mitmproxy mode based on attributes of the proxied request

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm running mitmproxy in upstream mode. In my script I'm inspecting for a header, `X-Direct`, which indicates that the request should *not* be sent to the upstream proxy and instead be sent directly to the server.

I figured out how to modify the proxy mode on a per-request basis using the `next_layer()` hook:

```
def next_layer(next_layer):
    ctx.log.info(f'next_layer = {repr(next_layer)}')
    if isinstance(next_layer, Http1Layer):
        next_layer.mode = HTTPMode.regular
```

This hook executes too early and I can't (or don't know how) to inspect request headers in that context. Hooking `request` allows me to inspect `flow.request` but by that point the server connection (via the upstream proxy) has already been established.

I tried just closing the server connection and instantiating a `mitmproxy.connections.ServerConnection` to replace `flow.server_conn`. This didn't work because, I think, other layers referenced the old upstream proxy connection.

What is the most elegant way to, based on the contents of `flow.request.headers`, switch from upstream to regular proxy mode for just that flow?