# Conditional upstream proxying with mitmproxy (PAC equivalent module/script)

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I have a super special proxy i need to use to access *certain* hosts ( it turns all other traffic away ), and a bunch of complex libraries and applications that can only take a single http proxy configuration parameter for all their http requests. Which are of course a mix of restricted/proxied traffic and traffic that this proxy is refusing to handle.

I've found [an example script](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/v5.2/examples/contrib/change_upstream_proxy.py) showing how to manipulate the upstream proxy host/address in upstream mode, but couldn't find any indication in public API, that "breaking out" of upstream mode in a script is possible, to have mitmproxy directly handle traffic instead of sending it upstream, given certain conditions are met ( request target host mostly )

What am i missing? Should i be trying to do this in "regular" mode?

I invoke PAC in the title because it has the [`DIRECT` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_(PAC)_file) that allows the library/application to continue processing the request without going to a proxy.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found evidence that this is in fact not possible and unlikely to be implemented https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2042#issuecomment-280857954 although this issue and comment is very old, there are some recent related and unanswered questions such as [How can I switch mitmproxy mode based on attributes of the proxied request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702363/how-can-i-switch-mitmproxy-mode-based-on-attributes-of-the-proxied-request)

So instead, i'm pivoting to tinyproxy which does seem to provide this exact functionality https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/blob/1.10.0/etc/tinyproxy.conf.in#L143

A shame because the replay/monitoring/interactive editing features of mitmproxy would've been amazing to have